# How to resolve version conflict for Parselmouth and Pandas during installation of pytz?

Tags: python, pip, conflict

I'm working with a voice trainer model downloaded from [here](https://github.com/Mangio621/Mangio-RVC-Fork/releases/tag/v23.7.0) (Mangio-RVC-v23.7.0_INFER_TRAIN.7z). It has two dependencies - parselmouth and pandas.

When I'm trying to install pandas, it's automatically uninstalling pytz-2015.7, which is needed for parselmouth 1.1.1 and, when I'm trying to install parselmouth, it's automatically uninstalling pytz-2023.3.post1 which is needed for pandas 2.1.1.

What can I do to resolve this? I'm using Python 3.10 in Windows PC.

Installing Parselmouth
[image]

Installing Pandas
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue, I can't tell you what is wrong here but here is what I did to solve it:

- Restart from the begining and work with a virtual env (python -m venv myVirtualEnv) and activate it (youEnvFolder/Scripts -> activate)
- Run the next commands (pip install) in the terminal of the virtual env, also install all the libraries with it

If your python version is too high (Python 3.10.x seems to be the maximum for this tuto) change it.